# I delete the category and the product detail page which belong to the category are not found!

Tags: magento-1.7, category

I deleted a category and the product detail page which belong to the category are not found. It's a blank page now.

When I go to admin panel and edit the product's category and save it, the problem is solved.

But there are so many product pages that I can't edit one by one, is there another solution?

Answer (score 0):

you seeing the following page www.domain.com/categoryname/productname which is the product detail page of the categoryname.

Now you had deleted the category called categoryname and you are trying to access the same url.which is categoryname category is no more and definetly you will get page not found.

Now if you want to see the product detail page of the same product use the following link www.domain.com/productname or if you want to put all this deleted category product into another category.please create the new category and assign products

Comment: the default page of the product detail is www.domain.com/productname not www.domain.com/categoryname/productname ,I don't want to put the product into another category!just want to display the product detail page although i delete the category!

Comment: ok if you want to show the product detail page then use www.domain.com/productname but why you are assessing the detail page frm category/productname which is deleted.Instead use domain.com/productname

Comment: for example:my website is e8bag.net and there is a Category http://e8bag.net/daily-new.htm ,i will add product everyday to the daily new Category by date,when i delete the Category of the date (such as "2014-12-25")!the product detail page under "2014-12-25" will be blank!that is my puzzle!